# Remembering Screen Brightness at Display Manager/Startup

Tags: kubuntu, kde, brightness, display-manager, sddm

With using linux on and off on different PC's through the years, one issue I have not been able to solve is the brightness setting during boot sitting at the Display Manager.

I am running KDE version of ubuntu so I have sddm installed.  Googling and searching through the Arch wiki, I am unable to find anything relating to brightness setting when at a Display manager.  Once logged on, I set up a script to lower it to the brightness that I like best.

Is there any way to change the brightness when first booting, even an option to hardcode it?  From what I see, it is not a setting per display managers.

[image: pc specs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using a bash script and systemd services for anyone else that may come along and wish there was a screen brightness perseverance.

1. Make a bash script and place it where you see fit. Here is my example where I named it `Brightness_Checker.bash`.  Also create a text file names something like `Brightness_Checker.backup`, this will be for storing the brightness value. You will want to update `sLoc` with that path to the `.backup` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

bLoc=/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
sLoc=/home/kar/Programs/BashTools/Brightness_Checker.backup

bVal=$(cat $sLoc)

echo $bVal > $bLoc

while :
do
    cVal=$(cat $bLoc)

    if [ $cVal = "0" ];
    then
        echo 1 > $bLoc
        cVal=1
    fi

    if [ $bVal != $cVal ];
    then
        bVal=$cVal
        echo $bVal > $sLoc
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```

2. Within `/etc/systemd/system`, create a service file similar to mine where ExecStart will point to your bash script:

```
[Unit]
Description = Brightness checker

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/kar/Programs/BashTools/Brightness_Checker.bash

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. From here you want to enable the service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable Brightness_Checker.service
   ```

Then restart your pc.

Note: The reason I have it echo 1 if the brightness is 0 is due to something beyond my pay grade that resets the brightness to full when booting up.

EDIT: One thing I forgot to mention, for security, I would suggest making those 2 files root owner and remove write access from everyone but root otherwise any update to that script could be ran on next startup.